# How do I flatten data so that data in one table is joined to another where dates don't match, but history preserved?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.  I have two tables like so.

Table A has something like the following:

```
ID  Date       Data1  Data2
1   2/18/2017  X      y  
1   3/22/2017  a      b
```

Table B has something like the following:

```
ID  Date      Data3  Data4
1  2/20/2017  c      d
1  2/21/2017  f      g
```

The expected result that I'm after is the following data table after joining the info:

```
ID Date       Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
1  2/18/2017  x      y      null   null
1  2/20/2017  x      y      c      d 
1  2/21/2017  x      y      f      g
1  3/22/2017  a      b      f      g
```

So, when table A does not have any records for that day, it is pulling the latest known record from the other table basically.  I tried using an outer join, but it isn't pulling the latest known record from the other table when data is missing.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: select ID,Date,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4 from Table A join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID where TableA.ID=1;

Comment: SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan, that won't work.  This will cross join the dates.  I want the output to be 4 records where I have the latest information from the other table if there is nothing for a given date.  I'm trying to flatten the data per ID per date basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd get the rows with a full outer join (for which a `USING` clause would be great, but SQL Server lacks this). Then we would like to apply `LAST_VALUE`, in order to get the history from former rows, but SQL Server's implementation lacks an `IGNORE NULLS` clause, so that doesn't work. So we would have to go through the joined rows iteratively (recursive query) instead.

Or we can quite unsophisticatedly select the dates and join the last records less or equal to those dates:

```
select
  dates.date,
  last_a.data1,
  last_a.data2,
  last_b.data3,
  last_b.data4
from
(
  select date from a
  union
  select date from b
) dates
outer apply
(
  select top(1) a.data1, a.data2
  from a
  where a.date <= dates.date 
  order by a.date desc
) last_a
outer apply
(
  select top(1) b.data3, b.data4
  from b
  where b.date <= dates.date 
  order by b.date desc
) last_b;
```

If this is too slow, try the full outer join approach instead; that should be faster.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten.  I have made a change to make sure to only get the dates tied to that ID by adding the ID in the Dates table and adding clause in the last tables where the date.iD = last_a.id.